# regex quandry with replacing in sublime text

Tags: regex, replace

I'm finally getting comfortable enough with regex that I use it in my everyday work. It saves me a ton of time, and I get exactly what I type. The problem lies in that sometimes, I have no idea what I typed or why it works that way.

I'm working with using round brackets for grouping, which is incredibly useful when sorting through lists, dumps, yardwork, etc. But I've hit something basic that I don't understand

say i have a simple query that looks for a specific group of characters individually for instance:

```
([a-z])
```

this does exactly what I need it to. Now if I need to split up the result into one line per character I'm using:

```
\1\n
```

This also works wonders. Simple yet effective. But now comes my quandry. How do I add a one directly after each character? 
i.e.

Input:

```
john
```

Output:

```
j1
o1
h1
n1
```

I've attempted using:

```
\1 1\n #gives me a space
\11\n  #gives me newlines with a "1" on each line.
```

And the really interesting one:

```
(\1)1\n
```

which outputs:

```
()1
()1
()1
()1
()1
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I've read your question twice, and still not exactly sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I answered my own question

```
\11\n
```

does give me the desired result. But why? Shouldn't \11 backreference #11?

Comment: Most languages that support REs allow for only up to 9 backreferences (\1 to \9).  The backreference \0 or & is special in that it is your entire search string.

Answer (score 1):

I think the keyword to search for is "named capturing groups" for backreferences. http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

They probably only do \0 thru \9 for the exact use case you're describing.